# python: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

I was trying almost everything, and all the time I have the same problem :<

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

users =[]

@app.route("/user/<username>/set-password", methods=["POST"])
def set_password(username):
     data=request.get_json()
     new_password = data["password"]
     users[username] = new_password
     return "Set password of {} to '()' "\
         .format(username, new_password)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback your getting into your question verbatim?

Comment: `users` is a list. Items in a list are numbered. You want a dictionary: `users = {}`

Comment: you mean the whole problem ?

Comment: `"Set password of {} to '()' "` shouldn't that be `"Set password of {} to '{}' "`?

Comment: I did it @app.route("/user/<username>/set-password", methods=["POST"])
def set_password(username):
     data=request.get_json()
     new_password = data["password"]
     users[username] = {new_password}
     return "Set password of {} to '()' "\
         .format(username, new_password)

app.run(debug=True)

Comment: all the time the same problem :(( I changed "Set password of {} to '{}'

Comment: The main problem should be solved by the other comments and multiple answers. I'm pointing out something else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "users" is a list, and "username" is probably a string. You likely want "users" to be a dict:

```
users = {}
```